# curl url call in for loop?

Tags: shell, curl

I am working with bash and I am trying to make a curl url call in a for loop.

Below is my simple curl call -

```
curl -v --header "Connection: keep-alive" "localhost:8080/user?userid=52010&client_id=20&attr=0"
```

And I am trying to make this curl call in for loop 100 times -

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do   curl -v --header "Connection: keep-alive" "localhost:8080/user?uuid=52010&model_id=20&attr=0" done
```

I tried running above code as it is in the command line but it doesn't work and it gives me like this -

```
>
```

Any thoughts what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Ah never mind. When the typo is fixed the error went away. That is the reason the question is closed :) Just to let the OP know :)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon after the URL.

It should be:

```
for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do   curl -v --header "Connection: keep-alive" "localhost:8080/user?uuid=52010&model_id=20&attr=0"; done
```

Comment: Silly mistake from me. One last question - Is there any way we can sleep between each curl call for few seconds?

Comment: Sure.  Just put the sleep command before the done and add an extra semicolon.  You can add as many commands as you want this way. `for ((i=1;i<=100;i++)); do   curl -v --header "Connection: keep-alive" "localhost:8080/user?uuid=52010&model_id=20&attr=0"; sleep 3; done`

Comment: is there a way to run these API in a loop asynchronously? It seems to me each API call is blocking